# Cant access elasticsearch server that is running on VirtualBox

Tags: elasticsearch, virtual-machine, virtualbox, network-protocols

I installed elastic-search 1.4.3 by unzipping file into my virtualbox machine :

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

I can successfuly reach http://localhost:9200 from my console on the host machine.

But I cannot reach server from guest machine :

- i added port forwarding rules on virtualbox (local 9200 -> server 9200)
- tried to change network params in elasticsearch config file, but nothing change.
- i stopped firewall on host (ufw disable)

nothing change i cannot access elasticsearch server from guest machine :

- http://myserver:9200
- http://localhost:9200

anyone can help me ? Thanks a lot

PS : i can hit http://myserver:80 from my guest machine successfully

Comment: please try to scan your server using nmap to see the port 9200 is already open or not.

Comment: Seems to be not : only 22 80 and 443 :/

Comment: then perhaps there is an error when installing the elastic search or there is some apps that somehow blocks the port. Can you access the elastic search from inside the server it self?

Comment: yes already said : I can successfuly reach http://localhost:9200 from my console on the host machine.

Comment: I openned port with iptables and it works now ! thanks

Comment: I have the same issue can you please let me know what exactly you did ?

Answer (score 7):

Please check params in

> /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
```

And port forwarding in VirtualBox.

Comment: This didn't work for me, perhaps it's not the way in 2.3.1

Comment: This is working. http.host: 0.0.0.0